# why awk turns a number into string when doing arithmetic?

Tags: awk

why a number as 0.4 is recognized as number variable but 0.3 as a string variable?

input: `echo | awk '{ c=0.1+0.3; if (c==0.4) {print "number= ", c} else {print "string= ", c} }'`

output: `number=  0.4`

input: `echo | awk '{ c=0.1+0.2; if (c==0.3) {print "number= ", c} else {print "string= ", c} }'`

output: `string=  0.3`

input: `echo | awk '{ c=0.1+0.3; if (c=="0.4") {print "string= ", c} else {print "number= ", c} }'`

output: `string=  0.4`

input: `echo | awk '{ c=0.1+0.2; if (c=="0.3") {print "string= ", c} else {print "number= ", c} }'`

output: `string=  0.3`

What is happening here? How does arithmetic works in awk? any help?

Apparently, using quotes in the comparison statement (as if it were string variables) works in both cases. However, in my code there is loop where I pass the value to compare from bash without the quotes, so I need the numerical comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're apparently being confused by floating point:

```
echo | awk '{ c=0.1+0.2; 
              if (c > 0.3) {print "number= ", c} 
              else {print "string= ", c} 
            }'
```

outputs

`number=  0.3`

What's going on?  When you add 0.1 to 0.2, you don't get exactly 0.3.  If you ask if the result is *exactly* 0.3, the answer is No, and your program logic then reports that `c` is a string.  But it's not; it's a number just a hair larger than 0.3.  Vis:

```
$ echo | awk '{ c=0.1+0.2; if (c==0.3) {print "number= ", c} 
                else {print "string= ", c}}  END { printf("%18.18f\n", c) }'
string=  0.3
0.300000000000000044
```